# Growth rate of one data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, dataextensions, custom-reports

How could I track the growth rate of one data extension? I have a SYNC DE that forwards my users who come from CRM and another system to the respective DE for each BU i have. But would like to know how to track growth rates throughout the month and also unsbuscribed and bounce rates. Is it possible to report or query this?

I used this code

The code:

```
<script runat="server">

var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('CountsDE - 2', 'Counts','Date DESC',['Secret'],[1]);


if (dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {

var num1 = dataRows[0]["Counts"]; //Sets the most recent count entry
var num2 = dataRows[1]["Counts"]; //Sets the previous count entry
}

var growthRaw = (num2 / num1) * 100;
var growth = (growthRaw).toFixed(2) + '%';

var rows = Platform.Function.UpdateData("CountsDE - 2",1,["Date"],[today],["Growth"],[growth]);


</script>
```

My DE:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on @LukasLunow and include the Unsub and Bounce part of your answer.

1. For counts, I would do as Lukas said and build a separate DE (countDE) to track Date and Count of the DE.
2. For Unsubscribers I would do similar with another new DE (unsubDE) to hold the Unsubscribe information.
3. And finally the same for Bounces with another new DE (bounceDE) to hold the Bounce information.

Sample Queries:

Counts

```
SELECT Convert(date, getdate())  as Date
       , Count(*) as Count
FROM [yourDE]

/* Action: UPDATE (Add and Update) */
/* Target: countDE */
```

Unsubscribes

```
SELECT Convert(date, getdate()) as Date
       , Count(c.SubscrberKey) as Count
FROM (
       SELECT a.SubscriberKey
       FROM [yourDE] a
       LEFT JOIN [_Unsubscribe] b
       ON a.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
       WHERE a.SubscriberKey IS NOT NULL
) c

/* Action: UPDATE (Add and Update) */
/* Target: unsubDE */
```

Bounces

```
SELECT Convert(date, getdate()) as Date
       , Count(c.SubscrberKey) as Count
FROM (
       SELECT a.SubscriberKey
       FROM [yourDE] a
       LEFT JOIN [_Bounce] b
       ON a.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
       WHERE a.SubscriberKey IS NOT NULL
) c

/* Action: UPDATE (Add and Update) */
/* Target: bounceDE */
```

This will give the total, if you want to include only unique entries in unsub and bounces, you can add the following to the end of the subquery (after the WHERE) `AND IsUnique = 1`.

I chose to use the action of `UPDATE` as it allows for if you are required to rerun the query during the same day that it will not fail the query, but instead update the current day's count with the new value.

---

**EDIT**

The below SSJS script should be able to get the growth percentage you want. **You will need to add a column of 'Secret' to each of your DEs with a default value of '1' to allow the lookup to work.**

I set it to pull the 2 most recent counts entries so that it is agnostic to the date segmentation. You can replicate this for Bounces, Unsubs, etc. with minimal changes required.

```
<script runat="server">

var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('CountsDE', 2,'Date DESC',['Secret'],[1]);
/* Retrieves rowset from your current CountsDE */

 if (dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
    var today = dataRows[0]["Date"]; //Sets the most recent date
    var num1 = dataRows[0]["Count"]; //Sets the most recent count entry
    var num2 = dataRows[1]["Count"]; //Sets the previous count entry
}

var growthRaw = (num2 / num1) * 100;
var growth = (growthRaw).toFixed(2) + '%';
/* sets growth percentage value with max decimal of 2 */

var rows = Platform.Function.UpdateData("CountsDE",["Date"],[today],["Growth"],[growth]);
/* Updates CountsDE data extension with Growth value */

</script>
```

**EDIT** I corrected this answer due to an inaccuracy inside SFMC docs - the second parameter of LookUpOrderedRows() in SSJS should be the number of rows to return, and not the 'field you wish to retreive' as is stated in docs.

Comment: So thanks, @gortonington! <br/>
Another question, if I wanted to know the rate of growth over the months? How could I do it? I created another column called 'growth'. Would you apply a line in the query like this?  <br/> '' , 100 * (count(*) - lag(count(*), 1) over (order by timestamp)) / lag(count(*), 1) over (order by timestamp)) || '%' as growth''

Comment: so you are looking for a percentage of growth from what? The last day? or are you talking a completely new DE to measure monthly growth?

Comment: Yes @Gortonington, in case I will run automation weekly and would like to know the growth rate of each data extension compared to last week. I would like this rate to appear in another column. It is preferable that only the two columns appear in one data extension.

Comment: You could try this, utilizing lag(), in theory it sounds correct - it is all dependent on if SFMC will accept the Lag() function and will do so without any buggy behavior.  If it doesn't work, there are a few other options in SQL that are a bit more complex and process heavy or you could just write a script via SSJS that does the math and updates your DE. You would have that run after your Query in the automation.

Comment: Hello, @Gortonington.

The query did not work, I had to open a case with the salesforce. As soon as I know I update you about the 'tag' function. What would be a bit more complex and process heavy workflow than you said?

Comment: Hello, @gortonington, <br/>
I'm sorry if i mess up you , but i'm not understand about javascript, i put your script in an automation (whith changes in some names), but the field 'Growth' it is not being filled. Could you help me, please. <br/>
Thank you for your attention<br/>

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Did you set the `today` var to the correct date? If not, then it will not add in any values. You could likely add in the following above the `num1` var in IF statement: `var today = dataRows[0]["Date"]; //Sets the most recent date`

Answer (score 2):

I would build a separate DE with two columns:
*Date* (primary key) and *Count*

You will run an automation daily, with a query activity, selecting current date and count of rows from the DE you want to monitor, and upserting the result to the DE created as per above. It will provide an overview of daily growth in the number of rows.